# Replacing an old damaged lath and plaster wall and found wood plank walls under it. What type of vapor barrier is needed and how should it be applied?

Tags: drywall, wood, vapor-barrier, lath-and-plaster

[image: Plank wall behind lath & plaster]

We purchased an old house (1900s) that has lath and plaster walls. One of the interior faces of an exterior wall was badly damaged and the lath and plaster had to be removed.  Under the lath and plaster we found this wood plank wall. It appears to be tongue and groove though there are visible gaps in places. The wall cavity is not insulated. I don't plan on insulating this space. I'd like to install drywall over the planks.

Should there be a vapor barrier placed directly on top of this wood plank wall and then drywall installed over it? Do I need to fur it out and create a gap between the planks, vapor barrier and the drywall? Here is the anatomy of the original wall: Exterior siding is wood T & G attached to studs. Next is a wall cavity with a few pieces of old paper and nothing else. The wood planks (pictured) are attached to the studs on the interior wall. It appears there was felt paper attached directly to the wood plank wall and furring strips attached over the felt paper. The lath and plaster appear to have been attached to the furring strips. I didn't find mold on the wall so it seems that the old wall was working well but redoing the lath and plaster is not in the cards.

I want to make sure that I don't create a moisture problem. The house is in Washington State. Cold snowy winters and hot summers. Also, is there a certain type of vapor barrier and drywall best suited for this situation? Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: So there's no insulation on this wall, and you're not going to install any?  Is the interior here a livable space?

Comment: If it's uninsulated and is staying uninsulated, and will be heated, my first impulse is not to add a vapor barrier. But I'm not 100% confident in this answer.

Comment: I'm thinking if it worked for 100 years, do it just the way you found it.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.  Very much appreciated.